# Oracle 11g - How to DECLARE a RECORD to store values based on Dynamic SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

**Summary**

Exactly as my question states I'm curious to know how I can define a record so that I can store the values retrieved via Dynamic SQL.  I have a table that stores SQL in CLOB columns.  The END goal will be to call a PIPELINED function using the query_id of the query that is to be run.  My issue at the moment is not knowing how to define the TYPE so that I can then PIPE the data out.  I'm unable to define the PIPELINED function due to the fact that when DECLARING a PIPELINED Function it needs a Type.  In my case the TYPE will change based on the desired Query contained in the Query Table.

**What I've tried**

I've read up on the use of DBMS_SQL and I see that there is a feature of DBMS_SQL that is `DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN` however it requires I explicitly define the columns - unless I'm missing something here.  Again... I don't know the column types coming back from the dynamic sql... they could be anything and in any order.

**Example of my problem**

The below code is the simplest example of my issue.  The RECORD I wish to populate in the example code below is `rec_cursor_query`.  In all other non dynamic sql it would be defined based off of a TABLE or explicitly defined using column names and the %TYPE keyword. `Can't use this: rec_cursor_query   employees%ROWTYPE;`.

```
DECLARE

  /* Cursor Pointer */
  cur_Query   SYS_REFCURSOR;

  /* Store Dynamic SQL */
  q           VARCHAR2(2000);

  /* Declare Record based on Dynamic SQL */
  --rec_cursor_query  ????table%ROWTYPE;  /* I realize I can't do this... but what can I do? */

BEGIN

  /* Fake Query Below saved into q */
  q   :=    q'~SELECT 1001 AS pkey, 'Jake' AS firstname, 'Johnson' AS lastname FROM dual~';

  /* Output Query just to show query was saved */
  dbms_output.put_line(q);

  OPEN cur_Query FOR
    q;

  LOOP

    FETCH cur_Query INTO rec_cursor_query; /* Again here... I can't do this due to it not being Defined */

    EXIT WHEN cur_Query%NOTFOUND;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur_Query;


END
;
```

Comment: @hotfix No... the Cursor could be opened for any of the Queries stored in a table within a CLOB column.  I of course left out the messy details in my Code as those details are not necessary in figuring out a solution to my issue.  The PIPELINED Function will take in as it's parameter the query_id and then PIPE back to the user the TABLE.  I'm missing one crucial component... Declaring the TYPE.

Comment: i don't know how many select's you have stored in your table, but you could write for each select separate procedure. one procedure for all cases is a bad idea imho.

Comment: @hotfix Exactly... I'm still unsure if this is even possible.  Or I should say... I KNOW it is possible due to my using applications that provide such a feature.  Now as I am developing this for myself I am unable to figure it out at this time.  That's the most frustrating part... knowing it's possible but not knowing HOW.

Comment: SQL always needs to know the projection, so I don't think it will ever let you have a query that says `'select * from [I don't know what yet]'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply this is not possible in Oracle SQL. SQL is strongly datatyped. None of this "if it looks like a duck" nonsense for us! The `table()` function only works with a pre-defined type (usually a SQL object) because it needs to know the projection. In case you're wondering, we can't use ANYDATASET or ANYTYPE as the return value for pipelined functions (PLS-00630: pipelined functions must have a supported collection return type).

One option to try is Inceptionizing your code by dynamically generating the SQL type for the pipelined function and dynamically generating the PL/SQL for the pipelined function which calls the dynamically generated SQL. But then you're in the realm of executing DDL as part of a query, and that's really messy. In short, I think this might work - although I have never tried it - but I would say this approach is too rickety for use in Production.

The other option is to realise that SQL is the wrong tool for the job. There are other languages which natively support reflection and such metadata-driven capabilities. Use weak ref cursors to pass data to client applications. Ref cursors map to ODBC and JDBC result sets, which can interpret the projection on the fly. Or upgrade to Oracle 12c which introduced support for implicit result sets in DBMS_SQL. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1).

Comment: Thank you for that solid answer.  Based on what you say in your answer it IS possible to Dynamically create PL/SQL as opposed to just plain SQL?  I have yet to explore this but was wondering if it was even possible.  Again from your answer it implies it is possible.  If so I feel it will still be worth exploring even if it's just for educational purposes.  Who knows... it might work for me as a potential solution.

Comment: It's definitely possible to dynamically build SQL types and PL/SQL functions on the fly. The problem is what calls them? You can dynamically generate code to call your dynamically generated code. But at some point the recursion has to stop, and you need concrete static code. *That* is always the sticky point. Particularly when it comes to deploying such code in multi-user environments. As long as it's a toy for one person you might get away with it.